# Mesh looks fine in Edit mode but disappears in Object mode

Tags: objects

Suddenly this anomaly struck, affecting only this model. I had just made the final edit of this model (snapshot 1), and was ready to save and export it. However, when I switched to Object mode, the mesh disappeared and other objects displayed in its place (snapshot 2). These other objects are used in Booleans to form the final object Back5, but they are not the Back5 object. If I select any one of those objects on screen, Blender indicates I selected Back5!

[image: Edit mode]

[image: Object mode]

I've never seen this kind of behavior in Blender before. Don't know if I made a silly setting change. Perhaps Layers was involved - don't think so. Perhaps executable was corrupt - installed 3.6.5 - everything the same.
I'm baffled. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Blend file added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because of *Boolean.001*, it fails, you need to switch to the *Fast* option to make it work (or *Exact* with the *Hole Tolerant* option activated):

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @moonboots for taking the trouble to resolve this.

Comment: You're welcome..........    ;)

Comment: Many thanks @moonboots for taking the time to resolve this. What surprises me is that a Boolean can have such an extreme effect without the slightest indication of a 'failure', as you say. Have I missed some basic documentation not to know the Boolean had failed or could cause such an effect? Or could failing Booleans try to provide some error notification?  (Added this comment separately because, apparently, it took more than 5 minutes to compose .  grr  All caused by  a carriage-return which is natural for me to provide format but apparently verboten in Comments [it's been awhile] grr)

Comment: Generally Boolean works, but I'm not always sure why its fails with an option and works with the other. The old versions (that used the Fast algorithm) mainly failed when the edges of the boolean object and those of the booleaned object were overlapping. Now if Fast doesn't work, Exact generally does and vice versa, but sometimes you need to switch the exact Hole Tolerant option on